# Content shift in pageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `pageViewController` displaying a set of images. Everything is fine when I scroll from right to left, but when I scroll from left to right, all images are shifted (a piece a the right image is still visible :

[image: First example] 
[image: Second example]

I must mention I applied constraints in storyboard between `imageView` and its `superview` for the `UIImageView` to fill the whole screen.

Here is my pageViewController :

```
ConversationContainerVC : UIPageViewControllerDataSource{

        func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! ConversationImageElementVC

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let segueName = segue.identifier
        if segueName == Segues.Main.ConversationEmbedSegue{
            let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UIPageViewController
            destinationVC.dataSource = self

            pageViewController = destinationVC
        }
    }

    private func setPageVCImages(){
        if contentImages.count > 0{

            let firstController = getItemController(0)!
            let startingViewControllers = [firstController]
            pageViewController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
            self.pageViewController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers as [AnyObject], direction: .Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
    }





    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = viewController as! ConversationImageElementVC

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < contentImages.count {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
    }

    private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> ConversationImageElementVC? {

        if itemIndex < contentImages.count {
            let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(Ids.Main.ConversationImageElementVC) as! ConversationImageElementVC
            pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
            pageItemController.pollImageAssociated = contentImages[itemIndex]
            return pageItemController
        }

        return nil
    }

    // MARK: - Page Indicator


    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Here is my `pageViewControllerItem` source code :

```
class ConversationImageElementVC: UIViewController {

    var itemIndex = 0
    var image: UIImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var pollImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.pollImage.image = image

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved this problem by setting the `UIImageView clipsToBounds` property to true and keep `aspect fill`mode . 
You can also set it through the storyboard by enabling "clip subviews" on your `UIImageView` identity inspector.